# Return the name of a variable rather than its object reference code

Tags: python, object

This may well have been asked before but I'm not sure the questions I've seen have exactly the same circumstances.

I have a program that traces optical rays. Each ray is an object, and each lens is an object. If, when the user attempts to use the method to propagate a ray through a lens, the ray does not in fact pass through the lens, I want the program to tell the user this fact.

Pseudo code:

```
class OpticalElement:
    ...
    def propagate_ray(self):
        if intersect:
            calculate new direction etc
        else:
            print "Ray %s did not intersect optical element" % (ray)
```

so that

```
>> A = Ray(args) # won't intersect lens1
>> B = Ray(different args)
>> lens1 = OpticalElement(args)
>> lens1.propagate_rays(A, B)
'Ray <Ray instance at 0x7688> did not intersect optical element'
```

Who knows which ray that is when there are 50 rays being propagated? What I want it to output:

```
'Ray A did not intersect optical element'
```

Comment: You can't do that; objects don't track what names reference them.

Comment: An object can have many different variables that refer to them. You should give your objects `name` attributes.

Comment: What would you show if the call were `lens1.propagate_rays(Ray(args), Ray(different args))`?

Comment: @chepner Well, I can't think of anything other than the reference code, but I was kinda hoping that there was a way if it were assigned to a variable

Comment: Could I have a reason for the downvote please, other than for the fact this is a duplicate? I stated that I was unsure whether it was a duplicate or not, having looked at several other questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that; objects don't track what names reference them.

Any object can have between 1 and unlimited names or other objects referencing them, as well, so what name would you pick if there are more than one or the object is referenced by a list or a dictionary? Or what if you passed those objects *directly* into your method with `lens1.propagate_rays(Ray(args), Ray(different_args))`?

The best you can do is give your objects a name attribute, then reference that in the `__repr__` of the object:

```
class Ray:
    def __init__(name, *other_args):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Ray({!r}, ....>'.format(self.name)
```

Comment: Ok, it was worth a shot. Actually, this clears up for me what was happening in the answers to the similar questions.

Comment: Also, I tried to use a concise example as I found the others confusing

Answer (score 0):

An object can have many different variables that refer to them. You should give your objects `name` attributes.